Contar resultados de paginado filtrado en CodeIgniter
Estoy agregando una vista a una app hecha en CodeIgniter para sacar un reporte de tickets trabajadas del equipo de soporte, y el resultado para hacerlo eficiente, lo estoy devolviendo paginado a la vista, sin embargo, tengo un problemita con contar la cantidad de resultados paginados, alguna ayuda o guia se aprecia mucho.
Este es el controlador:
public function reportsTable($page = 1, $limit = 10)
    { 
      $fromDate = $this->request->getGet('from');
      $toDate = $this->request->getGet('to');

      $fromTime = $fromDate ? strtotime($fromDate) : null;
      $toTime = $toDate ? strtotime($toDate) : null;
      
      $ticketsModel = new Tickets();
      $filteredModel = new Tickets();
      $query = $ticketsModel->select('tickets.*, staff.fullname as agent')
                              ->join('staff', 'staff.id = tickets.last_replier', 'left')
                              ->orderBy('tickets.date', 'DESC');

      if ($fromTime && $toTime) {
        $query->where('tickets.date >=', $fromTime)
              ->where('tickets.date <=', $toTime);

        $filteredQuery = $filteredModel->where('tickets.date >=', $fromTime)
                                      ->where('tickets.date <=', $toTime);
      }
      
      $offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;      
      $tickets = $query->findAll($limit, $offset);      

      # Pager
      $totalTickets = isset($filteredQuery) ? $filteredQuery->countAllResults() : $ticketsModel->countAll();
      $start = $offset + 1;
      $end = min($offset + $limit, $totalTickets);
      $lastPage = ceil($totalTickets / $limit);
      
      return view('staff/reports',[
        'tickets' => $tickets,
        'error_msg' => isset($error_msg) ? $error_msg : null,
        'success_msg' => isset($success_msg) ? $success_msg : null,
        'page' => $page,
        'limit' => $limit,
        'pagination' => [
          'total' => $totalTickets,
          'per_page' => $limit,          
          'current_page' => $page,
          'last_page' => $lastPage,
          'from' => $start,
          'to' => $end,
        ],
      ]);
    }

Despues de probar varias opciones, la forma que encontre de hacerlo funcionar fue de hacer dos queries a la DB, pero me parece que no es eficiente de esta manera:
...
$filteredQuery = $filteredModel->where('tickets.date >=', $fromTime)
                                      ->where('tickets.date <=', $toTime);
...

$totalTickets = isset($filteredQuery) ? $filteredQuery->countAllResults() : $ticketsModel->countAll();

Anteriomente habia intentado:
...
$totalTickets = $query->countAllResults();
$offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;      
$tickets = $query->findAll($limit, $offset);
...

Pero realizar esto "limpia" el query siguiente findAll que devolveria el resultado devuelve un objeto vacio.
Hay alguna manera de contar los resultados filtrados?
Usando: $totalTickets = $ticketsModel->countAllResults();
No vacia el resultado pero me devuelve el total, pero cuando el resultado es filtrado por las fechas, me deberia devolver el total filtrado y no el total absoluto.

En tu  controller:
$total_tickets   = $this->ticketsModel->contarRegistros();

En tu model:
public function contarRegistros() 
{
    $builder = $this->db->table('tickets');
    $builder = $builder->select('*'); //aqui puedes seleccionar el campo
    $tickets= $builder->get();
    if ($tickets->getNumRows()) {
        return $tickets->getNumRows();
    } else {
        return false;
    };
}

Espero te sirva.

Gracias, pero los registros ya los estoy contando, lo que quisiera es no hacer el query a la DB dos veces para hacerlo
